How to specify the default package for an action to import in Android Studio?
How to specify the default package for an action to import in Android Studio?
I want to add an import statement import android.util.Log when I try to fix the error -- Unresolved reference: Log in the statement Log.e(TAG,...). As following figure says.

But when I click Alt+Shift+Enter, import statement import com.mysql.cj.log.Log was added instead of import android.util.Log.
How can I solve this issue?

Usually when there's more than 1 option you'll get a menu with the relevant import-able options. If you don't, it might mean the import of android.util.Log already exists, if that's the case maybe check the Log part, it seems ok from the way you wrote it but it might not be within a function block if you missed a } prior or something like that.
